# How to get the text option of MySql select?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I'm pretty new to Php and web development. What I'm trying to do here is besides fetching the value of selected id **pck** which is **rate_perhour**, I also want to fetch the value of option **pack_id** to POST on an insert file.

```
<?php
include ("dbconn.php");
$data = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT * FROM packages");
$cek = mysqli_num_rows($data);

$select= '<select id="pck" name="pck" class="form-control">';
$select.='<option value="">-- Select Package --</option>';
while($rs=mysqli_fetch_array($data,MYSQLI_ASSOC))
{
  $select.='<option value="'.$rs['rate_perhour'].'">'.$rs['pack_id'].'</option>';
}
$select.='</select>';

echo '<input type="hidden" name="packid" id="packid">';
echo "<span class=style7>".$select."</span>";
?>
```

I'd tried the script to pass value into the hidden input to hold the id but didn't work as well.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{
  $("#pck").change(function()
    {
     $("#packid").val(("#pck").find(":selected").text());
    });
});
</script>
```

Parts of the POST method. It can get the *Selected Value*(**pck**) but not *Option*(**packid**)

```
<php 

include ("dbconn.php");
if(isset($_POST['cuid']))
{
  //Insert into 'reservation' table
  $pack =$_POST['packid'];     // Option
  $rate =$_POST['pck'];        // Selected Value
}

else 
{

} ?>
```

Comment: I cant't find the <form> tag. Does it exist in your code? If so, add that part of your code to the question to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.

Comment: Your select control is displaying a series of IDs to the user, and when they select one the value that gets submitted to your form is the hourly rate? Is that correct? And you also want the ID? I think the most common way to do this might be to have the ID as the value that gets submitted, and then look that record up again in the database when you need the rate. Otherwise, what's stopping the user from using common browser tools to change the rate to something more favourable to them?